# How do render react in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render

I have a function that goes through some promises and setState like so:

```
}).then((future_users) => {
      this.setState({future_users: future_users});
      console.log(this.state.future_users, 'tsf');
    });
```

this logs out an array of 3 objects
much further down inside my render method I have

```
<p><span id="users"></span></p>
{this.state.future_users.map(function(item){
  return (<span>{item}</span>);
})}
```

however I get an error saying `Objects are not valid as a React child`
where I can convert them into strings or so?

Comment: share your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you said is true, an array of objects is what future_users is, then you you are trying to do `<span> {object} <span>` which wont work instead you need to set it to whatever property of the object you want to display. for example if your user had a `userName` property you could do:

`<p><span id="users"></span></p>
  {this.state.future_users.map(function(item){
  return (<span>{item.userName}</span>);
})}`

and it would work fine. you can't put the object itself in the render method.

Comment: yes this is nice. but they are all concatenating each other in stead of.
123, 456, 789. it is doing 123456789. I would preferably like them underneath each other. how can I do this?

Comment: That's because a span is an inline element , use a div instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if this.state.future_users are with the loaded data:

```
{this.state.future_users && this.state.future_users.map(function(item){
  return (<span>{item}</span>);
})}
```

Comment: This wouldn't cover the error that he reported which was `objects are not valid as a React child` a map will just return an empty array if there is nothing in it and react wont complain about that